# Looking into dynamic variables created using pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-address

I was wondering if there is a tool in any IDE which can be used to "look" into dynamically allocated variables in C.

If for example I use the code below, it is not possible to use the watches (CodeBlocks) to track the variables, only the adresse the pointer is pointing to is displayed.

```
int *ptr=NULL;

ptr=calloc(1, sizeof(int));
```

Comment: The address a pointer holds *is its value*. and thus why it is displayed when watched. If you want to watch what it points to rather than the pointer itself, your debugger must support dereferencing (and most do to some degree). I.e. watch `*ptr` rather than `ptr`. Depending on the debugger, there is also syntax for watching a sequence (such as a pointer to a sequence of N `int`). Check your debugger documentation.

Comment: You could use a dedicated debugger like GDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any decent IDE that comes with debugger should allow you to view dereferenced value of an pointer. I am not familiar with CodeBlocks, but for instance Eclipse CDT does such thing pretty easily:

[image]

By default it prints just `*ptr`, but you may set it to view as array of particular size.

Comment: Thanks. I going to have to try out Eclipse.